# Process builder Done DML does not fire another process builder?

Tags: process-builder

i have a process builder which change owner of case record when i change status.and i have another process builder whose entry criteria is whenever owner is changed send chatter notification so this PB Never get fired whenever i change status.
but it fire when i change owner manually. Any Idea Why would This be Happening I have Tried Everything I know?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling another process builder on **"Record Change"** have you tried by **invoking another process builder**?

Comment: yeah i just tried that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

While Manjunadh's suggestion is also useful, to specifically answer your question, in your second process, have you enabled recursion?

---

[image]

Comment: No i haven't but if i did then chatter notification is sent  multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the second PB is invoked whenever record is created/edited or are you invoking the second PB only when record is getting created. Because I don't see any issue why the other PB shouldn't run. Check the invoking criteria of the other PB.

Comment: Both Process builders invoked criteria is record created or edited

Comment: May I have the screenshots of both the process builders. Because when you change the case owner in the 1st PB, second PB might be invoked, and it might satisfy any of the nodes before that particular node which checks for change of owner, and you might have not given evaluate next criteria in the previous nodes. These are just my speculations. Make sure to give evaluate next criteria in the previous nodes of 2nd PB